# Listings literate option breaks identifiers

Tags: listings

I wanted to raise the `_` char in code listings because the T1 font I am using places it too much below the baseline; this causes identifiers like `bla_bla` look horrible.
I am using `listings` so I thought I could use the `literate` option to search/replace `_` with a raised version.
Unfortunately, the search/replace option conflicts with the lexer which will break the identifiers when finding `_`.

A MWE to illustrate the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  columns=[l]flexible,
  basicstyle={\sffamily},
  morekeywords={to},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
add_to_list(x)
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[
  literate={
      {_}{{\raisebox{.3ex}{\_}}}1
  }]
add_to_list(x)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: preview]

Is there a way to get this behaviour without disrupting the lexer?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but I think it probably lies closer to `listings`' `SelectCharTable` and `lst@DefSaveDef` than to `literate`.

Comment: @Jubobs thanks for looking into this. Answers that do not meddle with `listings` internals/options but with the fonts themselves are also acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  columns=[l]flexible,
  basicstyle={\sffamily},
  morekeywords={to},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
add_to_list(x) 
\end{lstlisting}

\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
   \lst@ProcessLetter{"5F}{{\raisebox{0.3ex}{\_}}}\@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{lstlisting}
add_to_list(x) 
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```